# Right design in akka. - Message delivery

Tags: java, scala, akka

I have gone through some posts on how and why akka does not guarantee message delivery. The [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/general/message-send-semantics.html), this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/akka-user/Ih9HqTbI9NM/p0-Br_UXJ3EJ) and the other discussions on group do explain it well.

I am pretty new to akka and wish to know the appropriate design for a case. For example say I have 3 different actors all on different machines. One is responsible for cookbooks, the other for history and the last for technology books.

I have a main actor on another machine. Suppose there is a query to the main-actor to search if we have some book available. The main actor sends requests to the 3 remote actors, and expects the result. So I do this:

```
  val scatter = system.actorOf(
        Props[SearchActor].withRouter(ScatterGatherFirstCompletedRouter(
              routees=someRoutees, within = 10 seconds)), "router")
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)
  val futureResult = scatter ?  Text("Concurrency in Practice")
  //      What should I do here?.
  //val result = Await.result(futureResult, timeout.duration) line(a)
```

In short, I have sent requests to all 3 remote actors and expect the result in 10 seconds.

What should be the action?

1. Say I do not get the result in 10 seconds, should I send a new request to all of them again?
2. What if `within` time above is premature. But I do not know pre-hand on how much time it might take.
3. What if `within` time was sufficient but the message got dropped.

If i dont get response in `within` time and resend the request again. Something like this, it remain asynchronous:

```
futureResult onComplete{
  case Success(i) => println("Result "+i)
  case Failure(e) => //send again
}
```

But under too many queries, wont it be too many threads on the call and bulky? If I uncomment `line(a)`, it becomes synchronous and under load might perform badly.

Say I dont get response in 10 seconds. If `within` time was premature, then its a heavy useless computation happening again. If messsage got dropped, then `10` seconds of valuable time wasted. In case, say I knew that the message got delivered, I would probably wait for longer duration without being *skeptical.*

How do people solve such issues? `ACK`? But then I have to store the state in actor of all queries. It must be a common thing and I am looking for right design.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm going to try and answer some of these questions for you.  I'm not going to have concrete answers for everything, but hopefully I can guide you in the right direction.

For starters, you will need to make a change in how you are communicating the request to the 3 actors that do book searches.  Using a `ScatterGatherFirstCompletedRouter` is probably not the correct approach here.  This router will only wait for an answer from one of the routees (the first one to respond), so your set of results will be incomplete as it will not contain results from the other 2 routees.  There is also a `BroadcastRouter`, but that will not fit your needs either as it only handles `tell (!)` and not `ask (?)`.  To do what you want to do, one option is to send the request to each receipient, getting `Futures` for the responses and then combine them into an aggregate `Future` using `Future.sequence`.  A simplified example could look like this:

```
case class SearchBooks(title:String)
case class Book(id:Long, title:String)

class BookSearcher extends Actor{

  def receive = {
    case req:SearchBooks =>
      val routees:List[ActorRef] = ...//Lookup routees here
      implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)
      implicit val ec = context.system.dispatcher

      val futures = routees.map(routee => (routee ? req).mapTo[List[Book]])
      val fut = Future.sequence(futures)

      val caller = sender //Important to not close over sender
      fut onComplete{
        case Success(books) => caller ! books.flatten

        case Failure(ex) => caller ! Status.Failure(ex)
      }
  }
}
```

Now that's not going to be our final code, but it's an approximation of what your sample was attempting to do.  In this example, if any one of the downstream routees fails/times out, we will hit our `Failure` block, and the caller will also get a failure.  If they all succeed, the caller will get the aggregate List of `Book` objects instead.

Now onto your questions.  First, you ask if you should send a request to all of the actors again if you do not get an answer from one of the routees within the timeout.  The answer to this question really up to you.  Would you allow your user on the other end to see a partial result (i.e. the results from 2 of the 3 actors), or does it always have to be the full set of results every time?  If the answer is yes, you could tweak the code that is sending to the routees to look like this:

```
val futures = routees.map(routee => (routee ? req).mapTo[List[Book]].recover{
  case ex =>
    //probably log something here
    List()
})
```

With this code, if any of the routees timesout or fails for any reason, an empty list of 'Book` will be substituted in for the response instead of the failure.  Now, if you can't live with partial results, then you could resend the entire request again, but you have to remember that there is probably someone on the other end waiting for their book results and they don't want to wait forever.

For your second question, you ask if what if your timeout is premature?  The timeout value you select is going to be completely up to you, but it most likely should be based on two factors.  The first factor will come from testing the call times of the searches.  Find out on average how long it takes and select a value based on that with a little cushion just to be safe.  The second factor is how long someone on the other end is willing to wait for their results.  You could just be very conservative in your timeout, making it like 60 seconds just to be safe, but if there is indeed someone on the other end waiting for results, how long are they willing to wait?  I'd rather get a failure response indicating that I should try again instead of waiting forever.  So taking those two factors into account, you should select a value that will allow you to get responses a very high percentage of the time while still not making the caller on the other end wait too long.

For question 3, you ask what happens if the message gets dropped.  In this case I'm guessing that the future for whoever was to receive that message will just timeout because it will not get a response because the recipient actor will never receive a message to respond to.  Akka is not JMS; it doesn't have acknowledgement modes where a message can be resent a number of times if the recipient does not receive and ack the message.

Also, as you can see from my example, I agree with not blocking on the aggregate `Future` by using `Await`.  I prefer using the non-blocking callbacks.  Blocking in a receive function is not ideal as that `Actor` instance will stop processing its mailbox until that blocking operation completes.  By using a non-blocking callback, you free that instance up to go back to processing its mailbox and allow the handling of the result to be just another job that is executed in the `ExecutionContext`, decoupled from the actor processing its mailbox.

Now if you really want to not waste communications when the network is not reliable, you could look into the [Reliable Proxy](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/reliable-proxy.html) available in Akka 2.2.  If you don't want to go this route, you could roll it yourself by sending `ping` type messages to the routees periodically.  If one does not respond in time, you mark it as down and do not send messages to it until you can get a reliable (in a very short amount of time) `ping` from it, sort of like a FSM per routee.  Either of these can work if you absolutely need this behavior, but you need to remember that these solutions add complexity and should only be employed if you absolutely need this behavior.  If you're developing bank software and you absolutely need guaranteed delivery semantics as bad financial implications will result otherwise, by all means go with this kind of approach.  Just be judicious in deciding if you need something like this because I bet 90% of the time you don't.  In your model, the only person probably affected by waiting on something that you might have already known won't be successful is the caller on the other end.  By using non-blocking callbacks in the actor, it's not being halted by the fact that something might take a long time; it's already moved in to its next message.  You also do need to be careful if you decide to resubmit on failure.  You don't want to flood the receiving actors mailboxes.  If you decide to resend, cap it at a fixed number of times.

One other possible approach if you need these guaranteed kind of semantics might be to look into Akka's [Clustering Model](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.4/cluster/index.html).  If you clustered the downstream routees, and one of the servers was failing, then all traffic would be routed to the node that was still up until that other node recovered.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. This deserves some bounty from my side :). Also can you please answer the other questions I mentioned after the 3-questions. I am trying to thing of the behavior considering the fact that there can be some message dropdown.

Comment: Added a little more info, but still not sure I 100% answered your questions.  Hope it helps though.

Comment: Ok. So to summarize I should avoid considering message drop-down's and rather focus on `within` time. If it takes more than `within` time, then it can be considered as message dropped (in most cases) and subsequent action can be taken. The only issue can be in case where `within` time is large(say Image processing task), in those cases I can use other alternatives, or say have `ack`. General question, from practice: In places with decent connection, how often do messages get dropped?

Comment: I agree with your first statement; only go to more extreme measures if the situation really warrants it, and to me, a search operation (read operation) does not really warrant it some other scenarios might.  If you had a good stable connection, I would imagine a fractional drop off rate, well below 1%.

Comment: Why do you assign sender to val "caller"? I noticed in my (similar) practice code, if I try to use "sender" the message never comes back. I guess it begs the question of what sender is , at any given moment? - thanks

Comment: @LaloInDublin, on an `Actor`, `sender` is a mutable `ActorRef` var representing who was the sender of the current message being processed.  As the `onComplete` callback is async, that means that the `sender` could change out from underneath you before you have a change to send a response back to it.  In more technical terms, this is called closing over mutable state and should be avoided in this context.  Trapping it in a separate `val` before going into the callback and then using that `val` instead assures that you can route the response back to the original sender.

Comment: @cmbaxter thank you very much for taking the time, very informative and helpful!

Comment: This answered most of my doubts about guaranteed delivery. Thanks!

Comment: Waiting 10 second and resend message only good if there are connection problems, but what if there are no connation problems? What if delay arise due to server load? For example server is busy and can not responce to the message during 10 seconds. Client consider that mesage is lost and send additional 2 messages. Server become free process **first** message and send a response. Client get response to the **first** message. And server continue processing unnecessary 2 messages. How to resolve this situation? I do not expert of akka, but I think there must be another solution than just wait.

Comment: The Reliable Proxy link in the answer is not for the latest documentation that discusses how to implement.  Here is the consinstently current link: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/contrib/reliable-proxy.html